# Tweet replies and notifications are missing

Tags: twitter, notifications, reply

I built an automatic reply bot on Twitter and at first it seems to work fine. 
However, after some weeks running, I cannot see the replies from the bot anymore.

Concretely, when I tweet to the bot, I don't see the reply and notification, but If I log in as the bot, I see all the replies (only the bot can see the replies).
For sure, I always include @username at the beginning of replies and use the parameter `in_reply_to_status_id`. Moreover, my tweet is specific for the bot and nobody has replied to it, so it isn't a problem with a very large number of replies.

Is that a problem with Twitter platform?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Twitter has flagged my account due to weird behavior, which is posting plenty of messages against the bot with similar content.
In fact, my Twitter account is blocked after some time. Unblocking it solves the problem.